# TensorFlow prediction runs for deleted images also

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition

We are using tensorflow library for face recognition. Our code works fine for single images. But when we run it as an API, the prediction time increases for every subsequent request. This happens because it searches for previously predicted images as well which should ideally not happen. Please find below the code I am using.

```
def train:   
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
        test_set = _get_test_data(input_directory)

        images, labels = _load_images_and_labels(test_set, image_size=160, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              num_threads=4, num_epochs=1)

        _load_model(model_filepath=model_path)

        init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(init_op)

        images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
        embedding_layer = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
        phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)

        emb_array, label_array = _create_embeddings(embedding_layer, images, labels, images_placeholder,
                                                phase_train_placeholder, sess)

        classifier_filename = classifier_output_path

        class_name, prob = _evaluate_classifier(emb_array, label_array, classifier_filename)
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

def _create_embeddings(embedding_layer, images, labels, images_placeholder, phase_train_placeholder, sess):
    emb_array = None
    label_array = None
    try:
        i = 0
        while True:
            print("batch images")
            batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run([images, labels])
            print('Processing iteration {} batch of size: {}'.format(i, len(batch_labels)))
            emb = sess.run(embedding_layer,
                       feed_dict={images_placeholder: batch_images, phase_train_placeholder: False})

            emb_array = np.concatenate([emb_array, emb]) if emb_array is not None else emb
            label_array = np.concatenate([label_array, batch_labels]) if label_array is not None else batch_labels
            i += 1

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        pass

return emb_array, label_array
```

It searches for previously predicted images at

```
`batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run([images, labels])`
```

in the create embedding function. I think this is the problem of some unclosed threads because of which sess.run runs for all queued threads. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During debugging I found that previously predicted images information was in default graph which is picked during execution of following lines

```
    images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    embedding_layer = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
```

so by resetting graph before start of session will solve the problem of scanning previously predicted images as

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```